# Set mails read if they were read in another folder

Tags: vba, outlook

I'm trying to make an outlook macro, which will 'update' the mails. I have an Inbox folder and an another one. (2 mail accunts)

There is a rule, which is copying the mail from another folder to my inbox.

My goal is to set the mail as read in another folder, if it was read in the Inbox folder.

```
Sub precitane()

Dim myNameSpace As Outlook.NameSpace
Dim myInbox As Outlook.Folder
Dim myDestFolder As Outlook.Folder
Dim mydeffolder As Outlook.Folder
Dim items As Object
Dim defitems As Object

Set myNameSpace = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set myDestFolder = myNameSpace.Folders("") 'mymail
Set mydeffolder = myNameSpace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
   
For Each items In myDestFolder.items
For Each defitems In mydeffolder.items

If TypeOf items Is Outlook.MailItem & TypeOf defitems Is Outlook.MailItem Then
Dim oMail As Outlook.MailItem: Set oMail = items
Dim defMail As Outlook.MailItem: Set defMail = defitems

If oMail.SenderEmailAddress = "" & defMail.SenderEmailAddress = "" & defMail.Body = oMail.Body & defMail.UnRead = False Then
    
oMail.UnRead = True
oMail.Save

End If
End If

Next
Next

On Error GoTo 0
    
End Sub
```

"" contains my mail...

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you tried with code from other than VBA.

I broke the If statement into separate parts as it is easier to follow and to debug.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub precitane()

Dim myDestFolder As Folder
Dim mydeffolder As Folder

Dim item As Object
Dim defItem As Object

Set myDestFolder = Session.Folders("mailAddress2").Folders("Inbox").Folders("Test")

Set mydeffolder = Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Folders("Test3")

For Each item In myDestFolder.items

    If TypeOf item Is MailItem Then
            
        For Each defItem In mydeffolder.items
        
            If TypeOf defItem Is MailItem Then
                            
                If item.senderEmailAddress = defItem.senderEmailAddress Then
                    If item.Body = defItem.Body Then
                        If item.UnRead = False Then
                        
                            defItem.UnRead = False
                            
                            'If necessary
                            'item.Save
                            
                            Exit For
                            
                        End If
                    End If
                End If
            End If
            
            Set defItem = Nothing
            
        Next
        
    End If
    
    Set item = Nothing
    
Next

Debug.Print "Done."
    
End Sub
```